# PHP 2.1 plugin with Sonar 3.7.4

Tags: php, sonarqube, phpmd

I am currently using the SonarQube 3.7.4 version and php plugin 2.1 . When I analyse the php project . It won't analyse the Php Mess Detector, and Php codeSniffer, Result shows the Rules compliance 100% and issue is 0 always. But it is worked in the Sonar 3.5.1 version. Whati am missing. Can you help me

Thanks

Saravanan.N

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you were previously using a version 1.X of this PHP plugin and after migration to version 2.X all your PHP Quality Profiles are empty. This misleading behavior is due to the fact that in version 2.X all past rules based on Code Sniffer PHPMD, ... have been rewritten to be based on SonarQube PHP parser. So it's up to you to update manually your PHP Quality Profiles to activate those new rules.